# How to find out the overlap between multiple gene sets using an overlap matrix/intersect function

Tags: r, rstudio, bioinformatics

I have eight different .txt files containing long lists of gene names. I would like to formulate some kind of code on RStudio that will look at the overlap between them. 
Does anyone know which function would help? I tried to use the intersect() function but gathered that it only works when comparing two vectors.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
[image]

[image: Screenshot of the current code]

Does anyone have any clue why an error message is still coming up?

Comment: In your screenshot (why not simply copy-pasting and formatting as code btw?), your last line won't work because the variable `inter1vs2` is not defined yet. *First* do:
`inter1vs2 <- intersect(genevect1, genevect2)`, *then* make the next intersections.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: To see the overlap between 8 different lists of genes. I would like to compare two at a time, giving me 16 values at the end of it (4 of which will be N/A as we will get no overlap when comparing the same gene lists).

Comment: @HibaAl-khaffaji I edited the code to get all pairwise intersections.

Comment: @ PlasmaBinturong Hi, I have tried to use your edited code and the following error message came up:  Error in ith_inters[[names(all_gene_vectors)[j]]] <- intersect(all_gene_vectors[[i]],  : 
  attempt to select less than one element in OneIndex. Any ideas what I need to alter?

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to load your lists as vectors. Assuming each line of a file contains a single gene id :

```
genevect1 <- scan("file1.txt", what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect2 <- scan("file2.txt", what=character(), sep="\n")
```

Then you can:

```
inter1vs2 <- intersect(genevect1, genevect2)
```

if you want to intersect with the next gene vectors:

```
inter1vs2vs3 <- intersect(inter1vs2, genevect3)
```

**[EDIT]**

To loop through your files:

```
filelist <- list(data.file1, data.file2, data.file3, etc)  # CHANGE "etc"
# "Lapply" is basically making a "for loop".
all_gene_vectors <- lapply(filelist, scan, what=character(), sep="\n")

# Then make the intersection of *all* genesets (if that's what you want).
final_inter <- all_gene_vectors[[1]]
for (next_genevect in all_gene_vectors[2:length(all_gene_vectors)]) {
    final_inter <- intersect(final_inter, next_genevect)
}

# Or compute all pairwise intersections (untested)
pairwise_inters <- list()
# Iterate over all possible pairs i,j (i ≠ j)
N <- length(all_gene_vectors)
for (i in 1:(N-1)) {
    ith_inters <- list()
    for (j in (i+1):N) {
        ith_inters[[ names(all_gene_vectors)[j] ]] <- intersect(all_gene_vectors[[i]], all_gene_vectors[[j]])
    }
    pairwise_inters[[ names(all_gene_vectors)[i] ]] <- ith_inters
}
```

---

**P.S.**

I used the `scan` function to read your data, as it's a generic approach to simply read lines from a file. If you prefer and is suited to your data, you could use `read.table`:

```
genedata1 <- read.table("file1.txt", header=FALSE, row.names=NULL, quote="", as.is=TRUE)
```

and then access the "vector" object (a column) with `genedata$V1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried to follow your steps and have reached the third part where I am now stuck. I will add the screenshot of what I have done so far and hope you can elaborate on the last bit to take this further.